# Oneliner -a-switch - in Perl

Tags: perl

Would it be theoretically possible to enable automatically the `-a` switch if `-n` or `-p` is enabled and if in the code is a non declared `@F` array or a part of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I don't think you can do this; -a, like -l, -n, and -p actually changes the code presented to the parser, long before you'd know if the code uses `@F`.

Answer (score 2):

No.  One-liners don't have to declare variables, and there could be some already out there that use an array named `@F` for something completely different.  Perl 5 doesn't like to break backwards compatibility, especially for a savings of only one character (Perl allows you to bundle switches, like `-an`).